# How to set key name and file name same in object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Below is the object and my requirement is, the file name and it value should be same. How can we do that?

```js
const obj = {
  email: this.formUser.value.email,
  phoneNumber: this.formUser.value.mobile,
  profileImageName: file,
  fileObj: {
    // want the same logo.png to be the key name here
    file: {
      fileName: file, //value is logo.png
      fileDescription: this.formUser.value.fileDescription
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` can be used for defining computed values as property name in a JSON object. For more info please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Below is an example for the same

```js
let myKey = "logo.png" 
let val = "Logo.png"

var obj = {
  [myKey]: val,
}

console.log(obj)
```

So in your case this can be done like below

```
 const obj = {
      email: this.formUser.value.email,
      phoneNumber: this.formUser.value.mobile,
      profileImageName: file,
      [file]: {// using [] will allow to use dynamic key names in json obj
        file: {
          fileName: file, //value is logo.png
          fileDescription: this.formUser.value.fileDescription
        }
      }
    };
```

Hope this helps.